# by mistake removed the very last key (LUKS)

Tags: luks

So I wanted to change LUKS key but by mistake I removed the very last key before adding the new one, and left the system with no enabled slot and is still on.
any suggestions to solve such a problem?

Comment: One solution would be to find and attach an extra disk and copy everything to that.

Comment: What do you mean with everything the whole data?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: Do a backup before you try anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command: `cryptsetup luksAddKey /dev/the_luks_partition --master-key-file <(dmsetup table --showkey /dev/mapper/the_mounted_luks_volume | awk '{print$5}' | xxd -r -p)`

Substitute `the_luks_partition` for the actual LUKS partition, and `the_mounted_luks_volume` with the name that the LUKS container is mounted as.

That extracts the master key from RAM, and uses it to add a new key. See https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1543373 for more details.